# JMeter (for Load Test) set duration 1 hr But terminated before 1 hr

Tags: jmeter

Help me pls, 
Jmeter terminated before 1 hr(set duration)
I run Jmeter Test Plan that it should be run amount 1 hours.

Comment: see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/how-to-run-jmeter-test-plan-for-specified-amount-of-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly inspect your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration, my expectation is that you simply don't provide enough loops, it should be something like:

- Action to be taken after a Sampler error: `Continue`
- Number of Threads: according to your test scenario
- Ramp-Up Period: according to your test scenario
- Loop Count: `-1` (or tick "Forever")
- Tick "Scheduler"

  - Put `3600` in Duration

[image: JMeter Thread Group]

Your test scenario might still end preliminary due to i.e. a [Logic Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) or [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) reaching the end of data file, if your test won't be working as expected please update your question with the test plan snapshot and *jmeter.log* file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **RunTime Controller**. It has the option of looping every request inside it according to your specified time.

Just right click on the **Thread** > **Add** > **Logic Controller** >  **Runtime Controller**

Then set the time on the **Runtime (seconds)** field.

[image: Runtime Controller]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Stepping thread group. It will hold or send request as per you need.

Download jar from below link.

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/